# Working with degrees of a circle in R

Tags: r, geometry

I have a bearing of X degrees and I wish to calculate other bearings either side of X. We all know a circle has 360 degrees but if I'm given a bearing of 0 degrees and I wish to calculate the bearings + and - 30 degrees of 0 how can I program this such that I am looking for 0 - 30 = 330 degs and 0 + 30 = 30 degrees?

Comment: @MrfFlick, post as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modulus operator (`%%`) can help you with that

```
x <- 0
(x+30) %% 360
# [1] 30
(x-30) %% 360
# [1] 330
```

In this case it will keep all values in the range `[0, 360)`. See the `?"%%"` help page for more information or even the [wikipedia page for these types of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Comment: Fantastic MrFlick, everyday I pick up little pieces of info, someday I'll be a real programmer ; )